# Does the Auto Assign Role Module not work with Custom form registrations?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have a custom user registration form at: somepath/register using hook form alter.

I set up auto assign role by path to "/somepath/register" and it does not seem to assign the role that I am wanting.

Does Auto Assign only work with content profile and not hook form alter registration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that depends on how you altered your form to incorporate a user register form. Do you insert values directly into the database, or do you call user_save()?

It may also depend on the url of your form, because I see in autoassignrole.module that there is a check for `arg(0) == 'admin'` somewhere which might prevent the auto assign process from being executed.

Comment: I actually altered the user_register form so it should just be like any other registration. I did not know anything about the arg(0) and admin. Hmmm

Comment: Yes, if you altered the user_register form, user_save should be called and all the user hooks should be invoked. Does Auto Assign Role work as expected when you temporarily disable your form_alter?